# I get this error: "The item you try to buy is no longer available" when redeeming my promo-codes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, promotion-code

I have an app in iTunes connect with the current status "Pending Developer Release". When I try to redeem a promo-code for the app I get this error: "The item you try to buy is no longer available". I have tried different codes and different accounts but no matter what I get the same error. The territory in App Store is checked in the price section in iTunes connect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I didn't have a contract in "Agreement, Tax and Banking" in iTunes Connect.